# others way to load sound for webaudioAPI except xmlhttprequest

Tags: html, html5-audio, web-audio-api

is there any other way to load webaudioAPI except xmlhttprequest ??

it seems xmlhttprequest can only played with local server like "localhost/blablabla"

I want make my game can play locally without any serverside like 'file:///E:/blablabla'

thx

regards

Comment: its seems I need to make my own arraybuffer for 'audioContext.decodeAudioData' without using xmlhttprequest
any idea to convert audiofile to arraybuffer without xmlhttprequest ??

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could recode the file as a data: URL.

Answer (score 0):

what is your goal when using the audio api? There are two things to use as a source. First, you can use the Source node, which you specify 192000Hz PCM. This is decoded by the `.decodeAudioData` as you know, from an arraybuffer. This takes a lot of time and power. A second much easier method is to use the `<audio>` tag. You can give this an src (even with file:///E:/blablabla), which loads pretty fast or specify it with a data-url (also much faster than the `context.decodeAudioData`).

Example HTML:

```
<audio src="E:/blablabla.mp3"></audio>
```

Example JS:

```
window.audiotag = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
function audioReady() {
    window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext||window.webkitAudioContext;
    context = new AudioContext();
    source = context.createMediaElementSource(audiotag);
    source.connect(context.destination);
    audiotag.play();
}
audiotag.onload = audioReady();
```

This simply lets audio play from the audio tag, but when the audio tag gets connected to the sourcenode, it automatically mutes and sends it audio to the audio-api.